# How does <a href="/test/" load content?

Tags: html, href

At first I am not familar with HTML.

I have been trying to study different websites as I build my own.

I cannot figure out how content is being loaded when the HTML says

```
<a href="/test/">...</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="test.html">...</a>
```

What is it loading?
I think I understand that if I see

```
<a href="/test">...</a>
```

then I just can't see the file extension (altho I don't know why).

But when there is another backslash so it looks like a folder, what is that loading and how? I am using simple javascript (.hide and .show) to change out my content, and using the hash value to make it linkable, but would prefer to have an URL that looks clean like `www.test.com/test/` instead of `www.test.com/test.html#test`

I am vaguely aware of mod_rewrite but not sure if that is what's going on when I'm looking at the href link in the HTML of a site...

Thanks very much, I'm sure it's an easy question but I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should break down your question into multiple questions. Regarding "/test/" it's the same as "/test" and it means the relative url to servers public root folder, then test directory (or any aliases) then the default DirectoryIndex setting (usually index.html/php etc.). In fact, the "/test/" form is more desireable, as far as I remember (not sure abotu this last one)

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! I am using Dreamweaver and when I browser preview my site using "/test" or "/test/" it opens up Finder to that folder, instead of going to the index.html that is in that folder. So I need to use PHP to set my DirectoryIndex? Or is that something that only happens once a site is actually online? Thanks very much, I'm very new to this...I'll continue to read more on my own, so thanks for your answer, and any extra info you can give me!

Comment: DirectoryIndex is a web server setting. Usually apache.

Answer (score 0):

In root directory

create a file .htaccess

```
  RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^test    /test.html/#test
```

Comment: Why `RewriteBase /`? Why using it when it's not needed?

Comment: if you want to redirect at sub folder then  RewriteBase /subfolder/

Comment: My whole reputation is based on RewriteMod responses... so I know what `RewriteBase /` is for... I was just wondering: *why* adding such a rewrite rule if it is of no use? It seems there's no need to add it. If there's no need... don't add it, this makes things cleaner from my POV).

Answer (score 0):

`/test` and `/test/` are the same and point to default website in `test` folder (in case of HTML-only it should be `index.htm` or `index.html`).